# Script to change PowerShell ExecutionPolicy

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, jscript, privilege-elevation

When I setup my system, I use a number of config scripts to have my cosy place to play.

Based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I run by double-clicking  the following `enableps.js`:

```
new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute(
   "powershell", "-noexit -Command \"& Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned\"",  "", "runas");
```

Because of the `-noexit` I can issue in the displayed  PowerShell window:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

and get as expected:

```
RemoteSigned
```

Unfortunately, when opening a new instance of PowerShell, the policy keeps to be `Restricted`.

If I run in a standard `cmd` prompt:

```
cscript  "path\to\enableps.js"
```

it works. But if I embed   the command in the `enableps.cmd` batch and again try to run it by double-clicking, it doesn't work. If  I right-click `enableps.cmd` and use the Runas-Administrator entry, it works again.

So how can I make things working with the standard double-click (plus  the related Windows prompt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the command and give it the `-Scope` argument so that it applies to more than the current session. Add the argument:

```
-Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 1):

### ... and the solution is:

Double click on the file:

```
// enableps.js
// -----------

new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute(
   "powershell", "-Command \"Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned\" -Scope CurrentUser",  
   "", "runas");
```

Consider replacing `RemoteSigned` with `Unrestricted` to allow running downloaded scripts too.

Credit goes to [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26223517/1851270), who anyway did not write the full code.

Comment: While I'm fairly fluent in PowerShell and it's workings I am unfamiliar with Java scripting, so I was not comfortable writing the full code in a language that I do not know. If you have looked at my previous answers you will see that I am far from too lazy to write complete answers.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: I edited it, anyway it was intended as a joke)

Comment: Sorry man, was my first day at a new job and was probably a bit high strung. Didn't mean to take it out on you.

Answer (score 0):

By default making system-wide changes will require you to elevate the process if it hasn't been elevated already. If you want your script to disable the execution policy at the machine level then you will either need to switch off UAC or else you will have to run your cscript using a shellExecute, which will present the user with the required UAC approval dialog.

Comment: Right Stephen, but before, despite the UAC dialogue, the change was not persistent. With the `-Scope` option it is.